# Grab reference, setting default value

Tags: javascript

Is the following code safe? How would you accomplish the same thing?

Say I have an object x. I want to add some values to an array for a key in x, setting that key to the empty array if it's not already there:

```
var x = {};
var a = x['k'] = x['k'] || [];
a.push('moo');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
var x = {}, a = 'k' in x ? x['k'] : [];
```

**EDIT**:

```
var x = {}, a = [];

if ( x['k'] ) {
    a = x['k'];
} else {
    x['k'] = a;
}
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't leave me with x['k'] === a? Interesting to see the "in" operator though. Didn't realize that was available.

Comment: That's a nice trick to get a to have the right value. I'm hoping for some comment on the style of what I proposed originally. I guess assignment being right-associative makes it safe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence